# PackageMaker installing the app file but not setting its custom icon

Tags: packagemaker

I have created an installer for my application bundle(.app) and the installer successfully installed the application in Applications folder but it is not setting the icon which i set previously before installation to the bundle. In Applications my application is seen with default .app icon. I tried to set the Icon file in plist file of the bundle, but no result. Anybody who tried this successfully please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all those looked into my question. After some tiring research, I found the solution. I am not sure whether it has any problem with other version of OS X. I am using Mac OS X 10.7.3 Lion. Here is the solutions worked for me.

1. Create an .icns icon. Apple bundle uses icns file as Icon file. You can easily create one using an icon converter. I used an app from http://www.img2icnsapp.com/
2. Right click the bundle and browse the folder of the .app and copy the .icns file to the Resources folder.
   ie. Contents>>Resources
3. Edit Info.plist file and add a key for Icon File, if there is no Icon File key. Set the value to your icns file name. (eg:- test.icns)
4. Now create the package from PackageMaker and install the package, you can see your application installed with custom icon in /Applications

:)